# How Can I link the codes to Command Button?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have a some part of the codes of a macro it's working below changing of the cell value. But I want to replace them as linking a command button + getting data from a closed workbook. Can someone help me about re-edit them?

Thank you for help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Chck As Integer, Cnt As Integer
    Dim Save As String
    Dim Subjt As Integer
    
    If Not Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing And Not Target = "" Then
        With Workbooks("Data2.xlsm").Worksheets("Datas")
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
            For Chck = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                Select Case .Cells(Chck, "C")
                    Case "Number"
                        Subjt = Chck
                    Case ""
                        If Save <> "" Then
                            Save = "C" & Subjt & ":Q" & Subjt & Save
                            .Range(Save).Copy
                            Cnt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                            If Cnt > 1 Then Cnt = Cnt + 2
                            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Cnt).PasteSpecial
                            Save = ""
                        End If
                    Case Target
                        If .Cells(Chck, "B") = "Number" Then Save = Save & ", C" & Chck & ":Q" & Chck
                End Select
            Next
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to explain exactly what you want to revised code to do - there's no way we can guess from "linking a command button + getting data from a closed workbook"

Comment: Well I want to link it to  a commmand button and I want to copy some datas from a closed workbook with a command button. This is working without a command button.

Comment: Make a sub in a regular module with the same code (but obviously there will be no `Target` parameter), and call it with a button.  It's not clear exactly what your difficulty is here.

Comment: ... and if you've already tried that then *show what you tried* and explain exactly what problems you had with it.

Comment: I tried and got error which line has the Target Parameter. Well What would you suggest me instead of the target parameter to make it working?

Comment: I think I should only re-edit this lines,


If Not Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing And Not Target = "" Then
        With Workbooks("Data2.xlsm").Worksheets("Datas")

Comment: Which sheet "Datas" or "Sheet1" has the event handler?

Comment: Sheet 1 is. Copying datas from wb data /ws datas to wb main/ws sheet1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in a regular module:

**EDIT**: made a few fixes

```vb
Sub CopyDataValues()

    Dim Chck As Long, Cnt As Long
    Dim Save As String
    Dim Subjt As Long, valA1
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsData = Workbooks("Data2.xlsm").Worksheets("Datas")
    
    Cnt = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Cnt = Cnt + 2
    
    valA1 = ws1.Range("A1").Value
    
    If Len(valA1) > 0 Then
        With wsData
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            'ws1.Cells.Clear
            For Chck = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                Select Case .Cells(Chck, "C")
                    Case "NUMBER"
                        Subjt = Chck
                    Case ""
                        If Save <> "" Then
                            Save = "C" & Subjt & ":Q" & Subjt & Save
                            .Range(Save).Copy ws1.Range("A" & Cnt)
                            Cnt = Cnt + 2
                            Save = ""
                        End If
                    Case valA1
                        If .Cells(Chck, "B") = "REAL" Then
                            Debug.Print "matched " & valA1 & " on row " & Chck
                            Save = Save & ", C" & Chck & ":Q" & Chck
                        End If
                End Select
            Next
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it but there is no a error also no reaction on codes either. I tried editing some parts of the codes but couldnt do it. Would you like to try it on my files? Maybe I do wrong somethings. If you have free time and you're interesting.

Comment: If you can share a link to an example file with the same content as "Datas" (no macros in that file please) I can take a look.

Comment: Here the link No macro, it's just data file.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QaurdD_8h_TxwcCv0Z3KvxQemKmz-uY7/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103802305714910803701&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: See updated code above - there doesn't seem to be any "number" in ColB so your posted code would never have made a match...  Also you need to be careful of case when matching strings - "Number" is not equal to "NUMBER" for example.

Comment: I guess I messed up somethings on the file. I'm going to fix it quickly. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

Change `Private Sub` to `Sub` only and assign the macro to your related button.

For the workbook first, you have to create an `excel object` to get the closed workbook in it.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that, didint work.